# How to COMPLETELY disable jack (front panel) detection in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, headphone-jack

I would like to COMPLETELY disable jack detection in Windows.

COMPLETELY means:

1) disable detection of headphones/microphone/etc plugged

2) disable detection of plugged/unplugged

3) disable detection of mono/stereo

I have Realtek HD audio.

I know how to disable point (1), with the following option:

[image]

This `The current connected device is` dialog appears on right click on highlighted jack and selecting `Connector retasking`:

[image]

I know how to disable point (2), with the following option:

[image]

This `Connector settings` dialog appears after clicking folder-like icon in upper right part of "Realtek HD Audio Manager":

[image]

But I don't know, how to disable point (3).

When I plug my headphones into `Headphones` jack, it detects them as Mono:

[image]

I don't need that detection too.

Comment: Why don't you just open your computer and disconnect the front panel audio connectors?

Comment: Because they don't work then. I need them to pass audio signal only, no any matter for stupid computer "think".